# Count names one time (per year) regardless of how many there are by year

Tags: excel

The problem is:

There is a table that gets data added to it each month.  I use this data for many different pivot tables and reports, so I am not able to modify it.  The user has requested that if its possible (and I assured him that it was) he would like to see two (2) single values of This Year and Last Year Doctors on the list.

The data looks something like this:
Doctor, In/Out, Date, Number

`John Deaux   Out     10/1/11     8`
`John Deaux   Out     11/1/11     3`
`John Deaux   Out     01/1/12     5`
`John Deaux   Out     05/1/12     3`
`John Deaux   Out     09/1/12     1`
`Billy White   In      02/1/12     2`
`Mike Adams   Out     06/1/11     6`
`Mike Adams   Out     10/1/11     9`
`Mike Adams   Out     01/1/12     1`
`Mike Adams   Out     04/1/12     6`

I would have 1 John Deaux for 2011, and 1 for 2012.  The same for Mike Adams.

```
TY    2
LY    2
```

Now I only have to count the "Out"(s), so I have to be careful of that.  Also, there is the chance that I would have to build this for the previous 12 months as well making it that much harder.

1 for John Deaux for the previous 12 months.

```
TY    2
LY    1
```

***TY: This Year - LY: Last Year**

Comment: This is slightly confusing - Could you show what you want the output to look lik ein your question please?

Comment: So you want to count all the doctors with out and only count each doctor as 1?

Comment: Does this need to be done manually or programatically? This will make a big difference in the solution.

Comment: It will need to be done programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Check this, this will check the B column for the year 2012/2013 and count the distinct unique values in column A.

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(YEAR(B1:B11)=2013;A1:A11);A1:A11)>0;1)) + CONTROL + SHIFT + ENTER

=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(YEAR(B1:B11)=2012;A1:A11);A1:A11)>0;1)) + CONTROL + SHIFT + ENTER
```

Comment: Updated my initial answer a bit later than expected. (sorry!)

Comment: There are two formulas, one for each year, and you need to put the cursor in the formula bar and press ctrl shift enter

Answer (score 0):

To do this manually:

1. Since you can't make any edits to the existing table, copy everything to a new table.
2. In the new table, add a column called Year. Use the Year() function to get the year out of the date cell.
3. Make another column called Count. Use `If(A2="Out",1,0)` where A2 is the cell in the In/Out column.
4. Copy the Doctor, Year, and Count columns to a new table.
5. Excel 2007 and above has a convenient tool called Remove Duplicates in the Data ribbon.  Use that to remove the duplicates.  This will keep you from counting a single doctor twice in the same year.
6. Create a pivot table, using Doctor as the row, Year as the column, and sum(count) for the value.